# Filters Syntax Explanation

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-nav

I'm trying to reproduce the filters logic in csharp and was wondering what do the following filters mean?

As a start, I created a parsing tree having LogicalOperator Node, ComparisonOperator Node, Variable Node, Value Node.

The idea is that I could create a tree like this

```
             =
           /   \
COST_CENTRE      12456
```

I'm not sure how to interpret these theorical filters

8*..9*

8?..?12

>A*

>12?A*

Any ideas?
Thank you,

Comment: I thought of using a RegEx in a scenario like Filter = A?C* but what does it mean if that filter becomes >A?C*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the problem [Entering Criteria in Filters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh879066(v=nav.71).aspx)?

`8*..9*` result contains all records in which the field has values from (starting with digit 8) to (starting with digit 9), e.g. 8, 88, 838, 9, 91, 9034234 and so on.

`8?..?12` result contains all records in which the field has values from (two-digit numbers starting with digit 8) to (three-digit numbers ending with digit 12), e.g. 80, 81, 89, 312, 412, 912 and so on.

`>A*` result contains all records in which the field has text values that is greater than A*, where A* is any string that starts with "A".

`>12?A*` result contains all records in which the field has text values that is greater than 12?A*, where 12?A* is any string that starts with "12" then it has any random symbol, then goes "A" and than any number of any symbols.

The most stupid filters I've ever seen!

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm trying to cover all scenarios with my Assembly. This helps

Comment: I'm also using NAV 5.0 which seems to be dumber than that... I ran a SQL Profiler and there are queries such as: ... WHERE Code > 'A*' lol

Comment: Well, with newer versions you will have pretty much the same results. A bit optimized but same. I can guess that condition you mentioned is used to fetch top N records from table with primary key 'Code' to show it on form. So this is fine.